# How to import XLSX file (which gets updated) via URL in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'd like to import a XLSX file into google sheets. I tried looking on the web for it but nothing worked for me.
For example I'd like to Import this URL: http://www.sportsbookreviewsonline.com/scoresoddsarchives/nba/nba%20odds%202015-16.xlsx

```js
/**
 * Convert Excel file to Sheets
 * @param {Blob} excelFile The Excel file blob data; Required
 * @param {String} filename File name on uploading drive; Required
 * @param {Array} arrParents Array of folder ids to put converted file in; Optional, will default to Drive root folder
 * @return {Spreadsheet} Converted Google Spreadsheet instance
 **/
function convertExcel2Sheets(excelFile, filename, arrParents) {
  
  var parents  = arrParents || []; // check if optional arrParents argument was provided, default to empty array if not
  if ( !parents.isArray ) parents = []; // make sure parents is an array, reset to empty array if not
  
  // Parameters for Drive API Simple Upload request (see https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#simple)
  var uploadParams = {
    method:'post',
    contentType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel', // works for both .xls and .xlsx files
    contentLength: excelFile.getBytes().length,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    payload: excelFile.getBytes()
  };
  
  // Upload file to Drive root folder and convert to Sheets
  var uploadResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/?uploadType=media&convert=true', uploadParams);
    
  // Parse upload&convert response data (need this to be able to get id of converted sheet)
  var fileDataResponse = JSON.parse(uploadResponse.getContentText());

  // Create payload (body) data for updating converted file's name and parent folder(s)
  var payloadData = {
    title: filename, 
    parents: []
  };
  if ( parents.length ) { // Add provided parent folder(s) id(s) to payloadData, if any
    for ( var i=0; i<parents.length; i++ ) {
      try {
        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parents[i]); // check that this folder id exists in drive and user can write to it
        payloadData.parents.push({id: parents[i]});
      }
      catch(e){} // fail silently if no such folder id exists in Drive
    }
  }
  // Parameters for Drive API File Update request (see https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update)
  var updateParams = {
    method:'put',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(payloadData)
  };
  
  // Update metadata (filename and parent folder(s)) of converted sheet
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/'+fileDataResponse.id, updateParams);
  
  return SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileDataResponse.id);
}

/**
 * Sample use of convertExcel2Sheets() for testing
 **/
 function testConvertExcel2Sheets() {
  var xlsId = "0B9**************OFE"; // ID of Excel file to convert
  var xlsFile = DriveApp.getFileById(xlsId); // File instance of Excel file
  var xlsBlob = xlsFile.getBlob(); // Blob source of Excel file for conversion
  var xlsFilename = xlsFile.getName(); // File name to give to converted file; defaults to same as source file
  var destFolders = []; // array of IDs of Drive folders to put converted file in; empty array = root folder
  var ss = convertExcel2Sheets(xlsBlob, xlsFilename, destFolders);
  Logger.log(ss.getId());
}
```

So this URL gets updated so I want that the file updates in google sheets automatically too.

Thank you!

Comment: You would at least need an apps-script to import this.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz, yes I know. I found some scripts but they're actually not working.

Comment: In the link you provided by clicking **File > Save as Google Sheets** you can get a new file as well as the URL. Correct me if I'm wrong, are you trying to download programatically this XLSX and then import this through Google Apps Script?

Comment: @JoseVasquez, Yes I am trying to insert the file, which can be retrieved through the link, into Google Spreadsheets through Google App-scripts. Like for example with =Importdata("Csv file"). Only unfortunately this does not work with an xlsx file. As mentioned below, I have already tried to find a suitable App script (see script), but I do not succeed.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz,   Here is the link to the code, which I tried: gist.github.com/peterstieg/d02fa5c59370267d16076ffa8418cd4e

Comment: @Calculuswhiz, Ok! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You should try to use DriveApp rather than understand XLSX format

As a simple approach you can import your XLSX file to your Drive then update it  every X minutes via Drive API 2 in Google Apps Script as an Advanced Service, here's my approach:

**code.gs**

```
function updateXLSX() {
  // This URL should always be the XLSX
  var xlsx = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.sportsbookreviewsonline.com/scoresoddsarchives/nba/nba%20odds%202015-16.xlsx");

  // If file doesn't exist create a new one
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("XLSX test NBA");
  if(!file.hasNext()) {
    var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(xlsx.getBlob()).setName("XLSX test NBA");

    return;
  }

  // Otherwise override the content
  var driveFile = file.next();
  Drive.Files.update({}, driveFile.getId(), xlsx.getBlob(), {
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
  });
}
```

This code will download the XLSX file and then update the file if not created, you can previously create a Google Sheets named as "XLSX test NBA" and delete lines **5-11** and it will override the XLSX format and will treat it as  a Google Sheets format.

**Time based Trigger**

[image]

I find this approach more efficient but not ideal since it's not using loops inside each cell in order to understand the Microsoft Excel Open XML Format Spreadsheet file. It's a ZIP-compressed and XML-based spreadsheet file so I'd personally avoid it.

### References

- [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)
- [Import data to Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/40608)
- [Drive API via Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)
- [Import to Google Docs types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types)

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: If this answer was useful, please mark it so another community members can see it.

Comment: I created previously a file named as..., as you said. but I get this when I try to run the script: ReferenceError: Drive is not defined updateXLSX @ Code.gs:15

Comment: Click on the **Services +**  and add **Drive** as I mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, but I get this error:GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.update failed with error: Bad Request
updateXLSX @ Code.gs:15

Comment: I'm not able to get this error since it's working on my environment, can you please share a screenshot of your Script editor?

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer that solves a lot of problems to us! Best regards,