# Google Sheets: Import only certain tab downloadable xlsx link?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the file in question, https://dshs.texas.gov/coronavirus/TexasCOVID-19HospitalizationsOverTimebyTSA.xlsx

This is a hosted xlsx which I've used [a solution similar to this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222237/how-to-import-xlsx-file-which-gets-updated-via-url-in-google-sheets)

However, this xlsx file has grown rather large and now getting 414 "Request too large". I really am only concerned with one tab in the original xlsx file.

Does anyone know of a way to parse the xlsx file prior to upload to grab a single sheet?